# With 5 years experience

Tags: grammar

I would like to use this sentence in this context:

> ... which would correspond to my field of study and experience.
>
> With 5 years experience working in ...

The Microsoft Word corrector underlines "5 years experience" and propose these two options:

- 5 year's experience
- 5 years' experience

Which one should I use in this context and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to say is that you have had experience *of* something else and that experience lasted for 5 years. You could just say:

> I have five years **of** experience working in...

However, if you don't want to use "of" then you do need to use the possessive apostrophe as your spellchecker is showing you. Apparently though, it cannot determine the context, which is why it is giving you both the singular and plural form.

If you had only one year of experience you would write:

> I have one year's experience working in...

That is how you use the possessive apostrophe with a single year.

However, as you have multiple *years* of experience, you should write:

> I have five years' experience working in...